# Constrain position of group of wiggling objects within another

Tags: objects, animation-nodes, collision

I try to animate a group of objects with Animation Nodes and I am using Vector Wiggle but I would like to constrain the position of the particles or other objects, within an inside of e.g. a torus. Just to emphasize, I do not want to use a particle system because it is not loopable.
I tried a rigid body and collision modifiers but that does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here i created points inside a torus using particle system and animated it using wiggle vector node. Using bvh trees we can find the points which are inside torus, the points outside is replaced with nearest surface point on the torus.

You can work more on nearest surface point to get more smooth animation.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I was not too clear - I do not want to use the particle system because it is not loopable. (I have modified the question)

Comment: @kwicher ok, i don't have any easy solution for that.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I figured it out. I could Shrinkwrap the objects to the inside of the torus. Obviously, if the wiggle is too big they will all move only along the inside surface of the torus so one has to play with the wiggle amplitude but it is possible to do, a relatively cool effect.